# How appropriate is simple linear regression?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, time-series

My machine learning professor gave us the following data:

```
                  Admission Fee ($)
Year Attendance Adult   Child   Group 
1998   117874    4.00    2.50    1.50 
1997   125363    3.00    2.00    1.00 
1996   126853    3.00    2.00    1.50 
1995   108363    2.50    1.50    1.00 
1994   133762    2.50    1.50    1.00 
1993    95504    2.00    1.00    0.50 
1992    63034    1.50    0.75    0.50 
1991    63853    1.50    0.75    0.50 
1990    61417    1.50    0.75    0.50 
1989    53353    1.50    0.75    0.50
```

The question is to find the expected gate admittance figures and revenues for both 1999 and 2000. I plan to use simple linear regression, as I have always done. But the question should not be this simple. Is linear regression good enough, given that the training data is so less? I have read about other regression techniques, but have not implemented them (like locally weighted linear regression).

Comment: For a simple table, start the line with four spaces to get a fixed-width font, which you can then align into columns with spaces. If you *have* to use an image, please trim unnecessary bits of the image first (e.g. with GIMP). -- Secondly, if your professor is giving you an assignment, typically they want you to use the techniques you're currently learning about in class - what are those techniques, and what are your thoughts as to if they are appropriate?

Comment: Your first step should probably be to plot the data. How linear does it look? Also, it seems that you don't actually have sufficient information to get revenues. (How many adults / children / group tickets are sold?)